# React: Code Explanation for "PrevState" and "=>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to react and try to understand better java script code.

I use the code below and it works: Basically, the function takes the previous state of the "description" and updates the "description" with the new value when the user enters something.

However, I don't quite understand how this is done in the code and I would appreciate an explanation (particularly regarding "=>", and "PrevState" and the interplay of both).

```
onChangeDescription(e) {
    const description = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentTutorial: {
        ...prevState.currentTutorial,
        description: description
      }
    }));
  }
```

I also want to log the user input with `() => console.log(this.state))` but I didnt found the right "place" to insert it in the above function.

Comment: I'm not sure what information you're asking for. Are you wondering about the syntax of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

Comment: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 1):

`setState` in react is an async process, so when your new state is dependent on the value of previous state then react suggest to use this `callback` format, where you get the last present value in state.

Regarding console, use below

```js
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentTutorial: {
        ...prevState.currentTutorial,
        description: description
      }
    }), () => console.log(this.state)));
```

Read more about it here
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous